# Implementing 2 keys table in sql

Tags: database-design, normalization

Considering this table >
TRIP Table :
( Code [pk] , Origin , Destination , Distance )
how to make (Origin , Destination) attributes has the constraint of composite key "can repeat if one of them is different" .

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site, What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where there complexity is. Use a `UNIQUE` constraint on a composite key.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  a int,
  b int,
  UNIQUE(a,b)
);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1, null), (2, null);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (null,1), (null,2);
```

But,

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES (2,2), (2,2);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_a_b_key"
DETAIL:  Key (a, b)=(2, 2) already exists.
```

If you're not creating the table but modifying one already made, you can use this:

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT foobar UNIQUE (a, b);
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the RDBMS used? for example: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Oracle does the same thing, but I'm not sure it provides for the unique constraint in the table. May have to use `ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT u_t UNIQUE (id1, id2);`